# Compiling Mono 3.x on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mono, makefile, arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

To get rid of the soft float vs. hard float ABI problem I tried to install an up-to-date version of mono on my Raspberry Pi with

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/mono.git
cd mono
git submodule init
git submodule update
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

The make command fails. The errors are as follows:

> ```
> make[6]: gmcs: Command not found
> make[6]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 127
> *** The compiler 'gmcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
> *** You need Mono version 2.4 or better installed to build MCS
> *** Check mono README for information on how to bootstrap a Mono installation.
> make[5]: *** [do-profile-check] Error 1
> make[4]: *** [profile-do--basic--all] Error 2
> make[3]: *** [profiles-do--all] Error 2
> make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/mono/runtime'
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/mono'
> ```

To fix this I tried to install mono with "sudo apt-get install mono-runtime" and then start the make again. But the error remains.

Is it possible to get Mono 3.x working on ARM (the Raspberry Pi)?

Comment: Just pin the `jessie` repository for future reference and install it from the pinned repository. Much faster and easier. Wheezy isn't getting allot of updates any more I don't know why they just don't switch to `jessie` already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Compile mono from a tarball, not from git. A tarball is just a compressed package that contains all the sources ready to be compiled in a standalone way. For mono, you can find the tarballs if you go to http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/ and click on the "Mono sources" link, which links to http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/. You would need mono 3.2.8 or newer because that is the first version to implement HardFloat support for ARM.
2. Keep cloning from git, but use `make get-monolite-latest` command before `make`. More details [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git).

Comment: How would I do that from Tarball? The mono online help is not very specific on that... ("If you obtained this package as an officially released tarball..." -> How/from where do I "obtain" it?)

Comment: Thanks so far! I finally got it to „make“ and „make install“ without any errors (at least as far as I can see). But when trying „mono —version“ I get „no such file or directory“. Is there one more step to take before mono is fully installed?

Comment: the reason for that is likely because you used the /usr/local prefix. If you use /usr instead of /usr/local, it may work out of the box

Comment: Also don't forget to run ldconfig after make install

Comment: @Boris, notice that I've updated my answer to warn you that mono version 3.2.5 is still not compatible with Raspberry Pi (it will apparently work, but fail miserably at runtime when dealing with dates or floats). So you need to use master for now (or wait for Mono 3.2.7, if that is the number of v.NEXT).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer, I had to do the following to get today's Mono to compile on on today's Raspbian on the original Raspberry Pi:

```
apt-get install automake libtool build-essential git python

apt-get install mono-runtime # don't think this is necessary due 
                             # to 'make get-monolite-latest'

umount /tmp                  # to allow the process to use the SD card as temp space-
                             # it's too small otherwise. Resets after reboot.

# create a swap file because you run out of RAM and you'll need to swap
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
mkswap /var/swapfile
swapon /var/swapfile
chmod 0600 /var/swapfile
```

Then:

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git
cd mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local --enable-nls=no
make get-monolite-latest
make
make install
ldconfig          # apparently necessary.
```

Delete the swap file after reboot.

Result:

```
root@pi:~/mono# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.5.1 (master/5377700 Sat May 28 15:57:46 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

ref https://neildanson.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/building-mono-on-a-raspberry-pi-hard-float/