# Mono showing often _wapi_handle_ref/_wapi_handle_unref_full errors

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, async-await, mutex

I'm running .NET application (.NET 4.5) on Mono on Debian/Raspbian (on Raspberry Pi). And very often, say 9 out of 10 runs, I see after a while:

```
_wapi_handle_ref: Attempting to ref unused handle 0x770
_wapi_handle_unref_full: Attempting to unref unused handle 0x770
```

Of course the "`0x770`" is always different.

The applications runs fine then a short time. But eventually fails - either hard or just stops progressing (looks like deadlock/livelock).

Anything guide how to pinpoint problem in .NET code causing it and help Mono resolve it?

Mono version info:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.3 (Debian 3.2.3+dfsg-5+rpi1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

On `3.2.7` (built from current sources) the app fails even harder:

```
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Buffer.BlockCopyInternal (System.Array,int,System.Array,int,int) <0xffffffff>
  at System.IO.FileStream.ReadSegment (byte[],int,int) <0x0006f>
  at System.IO.FileStream.ReadInternal (byte[],int,int) <0x00233>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_int__this___object_int_int (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:


Debug info from gdb:

Mono support loaded.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0xb519a430 (LWP 1456)]
[New Thread 0xb52ba430 (LWP 32577)]
[New Thread 0xb52da430 (LWP 32576)]
[New Thread 0xb5538430 (LWP 32574)]
[New Thread 0xb5b7b430 (LWP 32573)]
0xb6f05494 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  6    Thread 0xb5b7b430 (LWP 32573) "mono" 0xb6f07700 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0xb5538430 (LWP 32574) "mono" 0xb6f09250 in nanosleep () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0xb52da430 (LWP 32576) "mono" 0xb6e6de84 in epoll_wait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
  3    Thread 0xb52ba430 (LWP 32577) "mono" 0xb6f07954 in sem_timedwait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0xb519a430 (LWP 1456) "mono" 0xb6f09a3c in waitpid () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0xb6fd9000 (LWP 32571) "mono" 0xb6f05494 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0

Thread 6 (Thread 0xb5b7b430 (LWP 32573)):
#0  0xb6f07700 in sem_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x001fb618 in mono_sem_wait (sem=0x2eff34, alertable=1) at mono-semaphore.c:119
#2  0x0017a52c in finalizer_thread (unused=<optimized out>) at gc.c:1073
#3  0x0015f3ec in start_wrapper_internal (data=0x974850) at threads.c:609
#4  start_wrapper (data=0x974850) at threads.c:654
#5  0x001f1718 in thread_start_routine (args=0x92f628) at wthreads.c:294
#6  0x001ff824 in inner_start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#7  0xb6f00bfc in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#9  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 5 (Thread 0xb5538430 (LWP 32574)):
#0  0xb6f09250 in nanosleep () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb6f08044 in __pthread_enable_asynccancel () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x001f08f8 in SleepEx (ms=<optimized out>, alertable=162) at wthreads.c:842
#3  0x00160e80 in monitor_thread (unused=<optimized out>) at threadpool.c:779
#4  0x0015f3ec in start_wrapper_internal (data=0xa0e400) at threads.c:609
#5  start_wrapper (data=0xa0e400) at threads.c:654
#6  0x001f1718 in thread_start_routine (args=0x92f7d8) at wthreads.c:294
#7  0x001ff824 in inner_start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#8  0xb6f00bfc in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#9  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#10 0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 4 (Thread 0xb52da430 (LWP 32576)):
#0  0xb6e6de84 in epoll_wait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0x00161804 in tp_epoll_wait (p=0x2efd7c) at ../../mono/metadata/tpool-epoll.c:118
#2  0x0015f3ec in start_wrapper_internal (data=0xbead88) at threads.c:609
#3  start_wrapper (data=0xbead88) at threads.c:654
#4  0x001f1718 in thread_start_routine (args=0x92fb38) at wthreads.c:294
#5  0x001ff824 in inner_start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#6  0xb6f00bfc in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#7  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#8  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 3 (Thread 0xb52ba430 (LWP 32577)):
#0  0xb6f07954 in sem_timedwait () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x001fb6f8 in mono_sem_timedwait (sem=0x2efcfc, timeout_ms=<optimized out>, alertable=1) at mono-semaphore.c:82
#2  0x00163844 in async_invoke_thread (data=0xb6e16e00) at threadpool.c:1565
#3  0x0015f3ec in start_wrapper_internal (data=0xbea9c8) at threads.c:609
#4  start_wrapper (data=0xbea9c8) at threads.c:654
#5  0x001f1718 in thread_start_routine (args=0x92fbc8) at wthreads.c:294
#6  0x001ff824 in inner_start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at mono-threads-posix.c:49
#7  0xb6f00bfc in start_thread () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#9  0xb6e6d758 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb519a430 (LWP 1456)):
#0  0xb6f09a3c in waitpid () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000b1284 in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=<optimized out>, ctx=<optimized out>) at mini-exceptions.c:2299
#2  0x000277e4 in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=11, info=0xb5199548, context=0xb51995c8) at mini.c:6777
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  mono_array_get_byte_length (array=0xb4e54010) at icall.c:6121
#5  ves_icall_System_Buffer_BlockCopyInternal (src=0xb3512010, src_offset=<optimized out>, dest=<optimized out>, dest_offset=<optimized out>, count=4096) at icall.c:6192
#6  0xb6817a18 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0xff8

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Updated the question with version.

Comment: that version won't work with Raspberry PI, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797283/compiling-mono-3-x-on-raspberry-pi/20809260#20809260

Comment: so you need to use mono master branch

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. But that fails even harder (updated question). Maybe I need to wait for stable 3.2.7.

Comment: it will not get more stable magically, (you would need to help the mono developers to make it more stable), therefore the best thing to do is run your app inside gdb, let it crash, and print a backtrace, then copy+paste it into a bug report here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Ahh, I thought the ARM hf support was completely done, from the post you linked. Never mind, I'll try to get the backtrace from gdb.

Comment: Every piece of non-trivial software contains bugs. You cannot say that some software is not done because you found a bug. There will always be bugs even if the software is "complete" according to the spec.

Comment: You probably just found a corner case, otherwise it would have been fixed before.

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't want to offend anybody. I reported it. And will some others. Thanks.

Comment: I think the latter crash you experienced is not ARM-only, I'm also reproducing it on Linux... you know, this is the master branch, not stable at all, where did you report it? I need to confirm the bug, I'm almost done bisecting it

Comment: s/on Linux/on Linux-amd64/

Comment: It's https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17217 . I'm still hunting the _wapi_handle_ref/unref.